# upload a file directly into S3 using python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3

I want to download a file received from a http url, directly into an amazon s3 bucket, instead of local system.
I run python on a 64 bit windows os.

I tried providing the Amazon S3's bucket url as the second argument of urlretrieve function of python during the file extract.

```py
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, amazon s3 bucket url)
```

I expected it to upload the file directly to s3, however it fails with filenotFound error , which , after some thought makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you want to run a command on a Windows computer (either local or running on Amazon EC2) that will copy the contents of a page identified by a URL directly onto Amazon S3.

This is not possible. There is no API call for Amazon S3 that retrieves content from a different location.

You will need to **download** the file from the Internet and then **upload** it to Amazon S3. The code would look something like:

```
import boto3
import urllib.request

urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://example.com/hello.txt', '/tmp/hello.txt')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', 'mybucket', 'hello.txt')
```

Comment: Thank you. Seeing 'not possible' , settles my mind a bit. :) Nevertheless, Is it possible to run the same using AWS glue and get the file onto S3? i just want to save double hops onto S3

Comment: I think that Glue only processes data coming in from Amazon S3. It would be quite a bit of overhead compared to the simple example above. Another option is to upload a "manifest file", which is simply a list of URLs. You could configure Amazon S3 Events to trigger a Lambda function that could read the file, then run the above code for each URL mentioned. So, you just upload a list of URLs and they magically load into S3 (but you'd have to write the Lambda code to do so). this would be a good approach if you commonly need to upload dozens/hundreds of files.

Comment: I cannot fully comprehend your approach.
I ran above code on AWS Glue as Python Shell. It failed with Syntax error. I guess i need to run above code on another external entity and push the file onto S3.

Comment: Correct. AWS Glue transforms data as it "flows" through. It is not intended for running bits of code that do external functions.